# Return the content within a class as string

Tags: php, regex, tokenize

### **How do I get the whole content of a class as a string?**

Hi,

In my current project I have n modules and each module has 3 files. Each file contains some functions:

**Module One - FileOne.php:**

```
<?php 
    function method_one() {
        return;
    }

    function method_two() {
        return;
    }
?>
```

**Module One - FileTwo.php:**

```
<?php 
    function method_one() {
        return;
    }
?>
```

**Module One - FileThree.php:**

```
<?php 
    function method_one() {
        return;
    }
?>
```

Within the project environment each module will be parsed into a buffer based on the file.
This buffer will be later written into a temporary php file. In the end we have 3 temporary files containing all the content of all modules.

**Example:**

```
tmp.FileOne.php contains all functions of each FileOne.php file for each module
tmp.FileTwo.php contains all functions of each FileTwo.php file for each module
tmp.FileThree.php contains all functions of each FileThree.php file for each module
```

Instead of managing three separated files for one module, I would like to merge them into one file. I though about using class calls for each file. However I cannot find a good solution to get all methods as string from a given class within one file.

**Example:**
ModuleOne.php

```
<?php

class FileOne {

    function method_one() {
        return;
    }

    function method_two() {
        return;
    }
}

class FileTwo {

    function method_one() {
        return;
    }
}

class FileThree {

    function method_one() {
        return;
    }
}
?>
```

I have tried to use the [PHP Tokenizer](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tokenizer.php) but could not find a working solution to find only the content for class XYZ.

Something like this would be perfect:

```
echo GetClassContentAsString( 'FileOne' );
```

**Output:**

```
"function method_one() { return; } function method_two() { return; }"
```

Comment: Do you know about Traits in PHP? Just checking that you have observed all possibilities.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes I had a look into traits but unfortunately within the environment I need to create a physical tmp.php file containing all functions as described. Therefor I need to get the class content as string to save it as a file later on. If I miss something and it is possible with traits, please advise. Cheers

Comment: Sorry for offtop, but why do you need to create a physical tmp.php?

Comment: This is part of the project environment which I cannot change. It would be to much to explain the whole picture which is not needed for my question. Is it a good approach to use tmp.files - certainly not but it is what it is. I gave this information to give a better understanding however, the question stays the same: How to get the content of a class as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. As I see you cannot get class as string. But you could get lines where class defined using [reflection](http://php.net/manual/en/class.reflectionclass.php).

```
class asdf
    {

    }

$reflection_class = new ReflectionClass('asdf');

$result = implode(
    ''
    , array_slice(
        file($reflection_class->getFileName())
        , $reflection_class->getStartLine() - 1
        , $reflection_class->getEndLine() - $reflection_class->getStartLine() + 1));

echo $result;

// class asdf
//     {
// 
//     }
```

But you could retrieve extra symbols with class definition.

```
1;class asdf
    {

    }1;
```

Comment: It seems to work but is there also a way to exclude the class call itself from the result. I could use regex but would prefer a built in solution?

Comment: `class call` - what do you mean?

Comment: @Talisin , i have added lost line : )

Comment: Yeah I figured out the missing line - what I mean is that the result includes the class itself and not only its content. The result should be not include "class asdf {" as described in the output example above